# Change paypal acount in ActiveMerchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I need to migrate to another PayPal account and start receiving payments there. The previous setup is working great but I cant see to figure out how to migrate to the new account.

The existing PayPal configuration is as follows:

```
test:
  paypal_email: email@fake.com
  paypal_secret: xxxxxxxxxx
  paypal_cert_id: ASLJKDLA334LJ
  paypal_url: "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
  key_pass: 0000
```

In my PayPal account I go to "Business Setup" -> "Get your API Credentials" -> "View API Signature" and I see some different information that looks like this:

```
API Username: somename.butnotemail
API Password: ALKSDFLADSJLKAJSDASDALKSDJ
Signature: afalksdjfal.asdflkjalsdfjalksfjqwefasdfaksdf.aksdjfhaksdfha
```

First of all they do not seem to match and if I try to replace them the payment is leading to "Sorry — your last action could not be completed" page.

Can you please give me some insight on this? Am I looking at the wrong place? Where can I find the credentials I need?

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 0):

From reading around, it sounds like the API key isn't what you're looking for in Ruby On Rails.  I found this on Kestrel Blackmore's site -- it's to do with what happens when your credentials expire, but hopefully you can turn it to your ends as well.

http://www.kestrelblackmore.com/blog/rails-paypal-certificate-expiration

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the data in your configuration is referring to a **PayPal REST API App**? Check the following link (while logged in) in your old account, or create an app with your new account and use the generated credentials

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications